# Websocket closes as soon as it connects in node.js with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, sockets, websocket

I am using regular javascript WebSockets to communicate with my server running on localhost. My server is running node.js and using the websocket from here:
https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md

The socket's connect and can send messages, however the socket closes on the server side as soon as the onMessage function returns. The socket is still open on the client side. My goal is to keep a reference to the socket to be able to send messages from the server later on. Is this possible with node.js and 'ws' websockets? Thanks!

```
// Listen to sockets for chrome extension
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9090});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        ws.send("received")
    });

    ws.on('close', function(message) {
        console.log('CLOSED!');
    });

});
```

On connection output is:
    received
    CLOSED!

Comment: Why aren't you using socket.io?

Comment: @r3mus Don't ever use socket.io, it's not scalable. Use primus instead.

Comment: @Mathieu'OtaK'Amiot with a statement as bold as that, it's usually a good idea to provide an impartial analysis. In this case, so long as you don't go over the theoretical ~1800 concurrent connections per core limitation, socket.io is a great tool. Moreover, since primus is actually an abstraction layer FOR realtime frameworks, your statement does't really even make sense.

Comment: I haven't been able to successfully do it using a chrome extension, there were issues with cross-domain something which made it a pain. The extension isn't hosted on the server, its a standalone.

Comment: @r3mus Socket.io hangs at around 3k users (with 24 cores) with 100% CPU usage. Because of its RedisStore which is completely borked.

And don't tell me to do the Pub/Sub myself, because I'd go with sockjs instead (it's faster).

Primus is a tool of choice only because it provides a nice abstraction, and a socket.io-like API (which is really nice) to ws libs like SockJS.